# Set vba variable not showing in the place of reference variables

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim FilmtoFind As String
Dim Filmcell As Range

FilmtoFind = InputBox("Enter the Film Name")
Set Filmcell = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Find(FilmtoFind)

Debug.Print Filmcell.Address
```

Note : Local window the Filmcell value refernce varibale value showing blank..

Comment: As is, the code assumes that the `Find` was successful. You need to test `If Not Filmcell Is Nothing Then` to guarantee that... also specify the other parameters of `Range.Find`.

Comment: You're going to run into issues using `xlDown` if there are any blank cells in column B - you should use `xlUp` instead.

Comment: When using Find(), in addition to supplying the "what" parameter, you should also pass in the "lookat" argument (xlWhole or xlPart) or it might not be doing what you think/expect.

Comment: Before using this range in your `Find` method add the line `Debug.Print Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Address` to your code. This will print the address of the range to the Immediate window in which you are trying to find the the film's name.

Comment: Is the correct sheet active when you run the code?  If you don't specify the sheet in the range reference it will use whichever sheet is currently active:  `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").End....`.  You can shorten the code by using a `With...End With` code block.

Comment: I got the desire result but can someone answer me why find function not working with varibales why it is not able to identify the variable...if someone answer it will be really greatful..Exam test -1 var1 = inputbox("Enter your film name"), var as range , var = Sheet1.range("A1",Range("A1").endxldown)).find(Var1)

Answer (score 0):

Sub Howtousefind()

Dim Celltofind As Range

Set Celltofind = Range("b2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Find(InputBox("Enter the Movie Name"))

MsgBox Celltofind.Value & " was found in " & Celltofind.Address

End Sub

**I got the desire result but can someone answer me why find function not working with varibales why it is not able to identify the variable...if someone answer it will be really greatful...**